# Export Nodejs Server

Tags: node.js, angular, web, server

i made an angular-application and a node-server. I know how to export the angular-app to run it on a webserver. But I don't know how to export the node-server? I tried things like "node build" and "npm build"... but it didn't work. Does anyone know how to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Where you want to deploy node server?

Comment: At the end i want to host it on a webserver (www.goneo.de). 
I didn't find the step from hosting it local to bring it online.

Comment: Deploy your web server over a cloud service. For start, you can try Heroku(it's free). You can find many tutorials for Heroku server deployment. If any help required, feel free.

Comment: Thank you, i will have a look at Heroku!

Answer (score 0):

If you own a Virtual Server or something similar, you could basically do the same there what you did locally. Otherwise, you should consider a cloud service. There are many available, but for starters, Heroku is probably the easiest and fastest. There are indeed many tutorials available, one that I think would be particularly helpful since it also explains a lot about other stuff you should (in the end) care about is this [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/deployment). If you just want to have it up and running, just read the part about Heroku.